# vuejs: I want to disable beforeRouteLeave in certain situations. Or I want to activate only in specific situations

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using beforeRouteLeave to show a warning when doing screen transitions etc, but it's fired in all situations within that URL.

Strictly, I would like to make it work only while importing a file within that URL (when the progress bar is running).
Please let me know if there is an algorithm that can only make it work during the import, not the whole URL.

Please let me know if you have any necessary information.

Comment: What code have you written already? Please have a read of [this guide on producing code for a good quality question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then include and mark up your code in your question. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Was self resolved.
When there is an explicit variable that indicates a specific phase, conditional branching using that variable enables operation in a specific situation.